# How to use a wired headphone and bluetooth headphones simultaneously?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

hello I am using the latest ubuntu 18.04 on a Surface Pro 3.  How can I connect both a wired headphones and bluetooth headphones at the same time and play audio to both?

```
uname -a
Linux Surface-Pro-3 4.15.0-51-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 15 14:27:21 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88W8897 [AVASTAR] 802.11ac Wireless
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First install PulseAudio Preferences, it's available through default repositories:

```
$ sudo apt install paprefs
```

Open it, and under the **[ Simultaneous Output ]** tab, there is an option for virtual combined audio output. Enable it and go to:

Settings -> Sound -> Output tab

Your virtual device must be there, you can select it and test the audio. And don't forget to mute other output devices that you don't want to hear (i. e. builtin speaker)